# create-react-app command not found in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I tried to install create react app using sudo `npm install -g create-react-app` on my terminal, then this message appeared:

`/home/mahi/.npm-global/bin/create-react-app -> /home/mahi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js
+ create-react-app@1.4.3
updated 1 package in 11.7s`

Then when I am going to run the command create-react-app hello-world, it says create-react-app command not found. Then I searched for many solutions, I tried almost all of them, but nothing improved, showing the command not found again and again.

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: 8.9.1 @DhavalJardosh

Comment: As Miroslav said, try using `sudo npm install`, it should install all your dependancies and then everything will be smoother.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem and this is how I solved it. 
It will work on Ubuntu 16.04 as well as Ubuntu 18.04.

First, open up terminal and run this command:

```
sudo npm install -g -y create-react-app
```

After that, you will be able to use the create-react-app anywhere on your machine because it is saved globally.

Answer (score 0):

Are u sure to run npm install with sudo? I had same problem and terminal couldn't write to folder with commands. Does your `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` folder contains `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 0):

are you using `create-react-app` with sudo? because if you installed the package using `sudo npm install create-react-app` then it is installed for this user, try `sudo create-react-app` and if it works then you should change ownership to your user

Answer (score 0):

I use to have the same problem in the terminal when i write npm install -g create-react-app and them create-react-app my-first-app.
So i went react doc and i find npx create-react-app my-first-app that worked for me.

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

> If you read carefully then you will see after installing Yarn it tells you to add the following thing in your path.
>
> ```sh
> export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> `~/.yarn/bin` is for yarn binaries only.

Try it!

Source: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5156